# create json like key and value

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

```
var data1=[
    {"year":2000,
     "country":"Madagascar",
     "country_id":847,
     "indicator":"Current account balance - National Currency (millions)"
    },
    {"year":2005,
     "country":"Madagascar",
     "country_id":847,
     "indicator":"Current account balance - National Currency (millions)"
    },
    {"year":2000,
     "country":"Madagascar",
     "country_id":847,
     "indicator":"Net Income - National Currency (millions)"
    },
    {"year":2005,
     "country":"Madagascar",
     "country_id":847,
     "indicator":"Net Income - National Currency (millions)"
    }
]
```

this is my json data
i want to do like this using underscorejs

```
{
  "key":"Madagascar"
  "values":[
    {"year":2000,
     "country":"Madagascar",
     "country_id":847,
     "indicator":"Current account balance - National Currency (millions)"
    },
    {"year":2005,
     "country":"Madagascar",
     "country_id":847,
     "indicator":"Current account balance - National Currency (millions)"
    }
  ]
}
```

please can any one can help me to solve this problem
using underscore.js

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: So you don't want "Net Income"?

Comment: not like that i want to filter it based on country wise  uniq and its values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Underscore has a _.groupBy() method can do the heavy lifting, but it creates an object with a key for each value:

```
var groupedData1 = _.groupBy(data1, 'country');
```

Here's the value of groupedData1:

```
{"Madagascar": [
    {
        "year": 2000,
        "country": "Madagascar",
        "country_id": 847,
        "indicator": "Current account balance - National Currency (millions)"
    }, 
    {
        "year": 2005,
        "country": "Madagascar",
        "country_id": 847,
        "indicator": "Current account balance - National Currency (millions)"
    }, 
    {
        "year": 2000,
        "country": "Madagascar",
        "country_id": 847,
        "indicator": "Net Income - National Currency (millions)"
    }, 
    {
        "year": 2005,
        "country": "Madagascar",
        "country_id": 847,
        "indicator": "Net Income - National Currency (millions)"
    }
]}
```

To convert into an array of key/values, you can use _.each() and _.keys() to iterate through each country:

```
var groupedData2 = [];

_.each(_.keys(groupedData1), function (country) {
    groupedData2.push({
        "key": country, 
        "values": groupedData1[country]
    });
});
```

This creates an array of objects, one object for each country:

```
[{
    "key": "Madagascar",
    "values": [{
        "year": 2000,
        "country": "Madagascar",
        "country_id": 847,
        "indicator": "Current account balance - National Currency (millions)"
    }, {
        "year": 2005,
        "country": "Madagascar",
        "country_id": 847,
        "indicator": "Current account balance - National Currency (millions)"
    }, {
        "year": 2000,
        "country": "Madagascar",
        "country_id": 847,
        "indicator": "Net Income - National Currency (millions)"
    }, {
        "year": 2005,
        "country": "Madagascar",
        "country_id": 847,
        "indicator": "Net Income - National Currency (millions)"
    }]
}]
```

Comment: There are two indicators for each year in this sample data.  Do you want to pick a single indicator, or separate the indicators?

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the desired JSON format?  I'm not sure how the separate indicators should be displayed.